# How to access Wagtail Routable page routes in Django REST framework?

Tags: django-rest-framework, wagtail

I have got a Wagtail routable page with a bunch of routes defined:

```py
class MyRoutable(RoutablePageMixin,...):
  # stuff
  
  @route(<regex to represent /<album_id>-<album_title_slug>/<song_title_slug>/)
  def do_something_with_song_data(self):
    # do something with song data
    return SomeResponse
  
  # more routes
```

In Django REST framework, I am able to get the Wagtail pages with something like:

```
/api/v2/pages/<wagtail_page_id>/
```

What would the url look like for accessing such routes defined in a Wagtail routable page? I am looking for the proper way of getting:

```
/api/v2/pages/.../006-red-pill-blues/girls-like-you/
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't do this with Django REST Framework. Django REST Framework only knows about the data that exists on the Page object itself - in other words, the set of fields you edit in the admin interface. When you write a `@route` method, you're doing some additional data lookups, but immediately returning the results as an HTML page, so there's no way for Django REST Framework to have access to that raw data.

A couple of alternative approaches:

- Presumably your song data is stored in `Song` / `Album` models? If so, define a Django REST Framework endpoint for those models, not the page model.
- Create additional routes on the routable page, perhaps with a URL like `/<album_id>-<album_title_slug>/<song_title_slug>.json`, that return [a JsonResponse object](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/request-response/#jsonresponse-objects). That way, you can return the same kind of data that you'd get from DRF, without using DRF itself.